# TeamCity: Cannot convert type 'lambda expression' to parameter type 'System.Func`2'

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, teamcity

I have setup my latest project in TeamCity (version 8.0.5) and the build step Inspections (.Net) finds the following error in my code:

```
Cannot convert type 'lambda expression' to parameter type 'System.Func`2'
```

This line of code is

```
Dim bolPageValid = pageInfo.Questions.Any(Function(m) m.IsValid)
```

I am not sure why TeamCity say this is an error, as it builds and runs correctly within Visual Studio's

Any ideas?

Cheers

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but changing it to the following resolved the error:

```
 Dim bolPageValid As Boolean = pageInfo.Questions.Any(Function(m) m.IsValid = True)
```